# How to make a discord bot accept multiple prefixes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot with multiple commands and for the sake of relevancy I want one command to be used with a `+` prefix and another one to be used with a `!` prefix.

I have a config file with a dictionary that I imported so I could use those to define my prefix.

Here is what my prefix bot thing is:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT['DEFAULT_PREFIX'])
```

I tried making another prefix in the config file so it has two of them:

```
'DEFAULT_PREFIX': '+',
'SPECIAL_PREFIX': '!',
```

I could add a second variable such as client = command.Bot... but I already tried that and the default prefix (`+`) worked fine being used in my cogs.py but the special prefix (`!`) didn't work with my `report` command.

Is it possible to somehow have two available prefixes for commands to use? **Or even better**, to assign a custom prefix to one decorator? (I have tried doing `bot.command(command_prefix='!')` but had no luck).

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass a tuple as `command_prefix`: `Bot(command_prefix=('!', '+'))`, but that will allow someone to use either prefix to invoke any command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['first prefix','second prefix'])
```